# Error constructing temporary object whose constructor takes a single enum parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, enums, temporary-objects

Why is the below code invalid (at least using Visual Studio 2010 or [ideone](http://ideone.com/03QfTs))?

```
// E.h
enum E
{
  AN_E_VALUE
};

// C.h
class C
{
public:
  explicit C(E e) // explicit keyword is optional
  {}

  void Foo() {}
};

// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  C c(AN_E_VALUE);      // fine
  C(AN_E_VALUE);        // error
  C(AN_E_VALUE).Foo();  // fine
  return 0;
}
```

If the parameter is anything but a single enumerated type, it works fine.

The compiler understands the erroneous call as one with 0 arguments where 1 is expected. Why is this?

Comment: Compiler interprets that as a variable declaration. Your class has no default-constructor. Error.

Comment: Yup, this is a vexing parse. The solution (if you have C++11), is to do `C{AN_E_VALUE}`.

Comment: That's great -- indeed, adding the default constructor gets rid of the error. However, if I add it as private - as default constructing objects of class C does not make sense and should not be allowed - we're back to square one. EDIT: been staring at it too long... the compiler-generated default constructor _is_ private. #squareone

Comment: The solution is *not* to add a default-constructor, but to choose a different way of creating the object. `C(AN_E_VALUE)` is interpreted as a variable-declaration, it doesn't call the explicit constructor. What you need is `C{AN_E_VALUE}` or one of the other variants you showed.

Comment: Also, the compiler-generated default-constructor is public by default but your user-declared constructor inhibited its creation.

Comment: Instead of `C{AN_E_VALUE};`, `(C(AN_E_VALUE));` is also a valid workaround, and more portable: it'll work even if you've got to support pre-C++11 compilers.

Comment: @0x499602D2 But of course -- thank you for the clarification. No more edits for me today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C(AN_E_VALUE);
```

This declares an object of type `C` with name `AN_E_VALUE`. The error complains about the fact that you need a default constructor to initialize `AN_E_VALUE`, but no default constructor exists (and none is implicitly declared).
Have you ever tried this?:

```
int(a);
```

That's essentially accomplishes the same thing. Perhaps check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832321/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-declaration-like-int-x-or-int-x-10).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This syntax to declare variables has got to be one of the most horrid / least used features of the language.

Comment: @zyndor ... not very far away from that.