# Parentheses in left side of variable declaration

Tags: c++, syntax

I recently came across the following variable declaration:

```
QString(newText) = QString("Placeholder");
```

I don't understand how to parse this line: the use of parentheses on the left size of the `newText` declaration is puzzling me. How does the compiler process this line?

The declaration seems to work the same way as the more traditional approach

```
QString newText = QString("Placeholder");
```

Comment: Also see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832321/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-declaration-like-int-x-or-int-x-10