# C++ Returning Wrong Line of Code

Tags: c++

I was instructed to design an algorithm that would allow the user to calculate the perimeter and area of a rectangle, but that's too easy:

```
Perimeter = 2 (Length + Width)
Area = (Length * Width)
```

I wanted to build a program using a similar construction to one my professor showed us on the first day so that I could have a program collect data from the user, calculate the perimeter and area of the rectangle for me, and then output the answer back to the user. That was easy enough, so I decided I wanted the program to also tell me whether or not the length and width that the user entered was the length and width of a rectangle or a square.

With the code I wrote, the program always returns that the length and width entered are the length and width of a square. I am not sure where I went wrong:

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    //Declaration
    int length;
    int width;
    int perimeter;
    int area;

    //Collect Data
    cout << "Let's calculate the perimeter and area of a rectangle\n";
    cout << "What is the length of the rectangle?: ";
    cin >> (length);

    cout << "What is the width of the rectangle?: ";
    cin >> (width);

    //Calculation
    (perimeter) = 2 * (length + width);
    (area) = (length) * (width);

    //Output Data
    cout << "The perimeter of the rectangle is: " << (perimeter) << "\n";
    cout << "The area of the rectangle is: " << (area) << "\n";

    //For some reason, the code is not able to recognize what I have designed.
    //No matter what input for length and width, when the program executes it returns that I entered the length and width of a square.
    if ((length) = (width))
        cout << "Hey! You entered the length and width of a Square!\n";
    else
        cout << "You entered the length and width of a Rectangle!\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: As a side note, kudos for going above and beyond the assignment and exploring on your own. That habit will definitely accelerate your learning!

Comment: BTW, you don't need the parentheses around all your variables. E.g. `area = length * width;`

Comment: I like how you put () around the variables even though you don't have to I think it helps you understand the program better. [What is the purpose of a declaration like int (x); or int (x) = 10;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832321/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-declaration-like-int-x-or-int-x-10)

Comment: = is for assignment , == is for comparison. check your operators

Comment: Your compiler should have given you a warning about using assignment where it's ordinarily out of place; namely in the `if` condition. Let this be a lesson to _always_ take note of and ***fix*** compiler hints & warnings.

Answer (score 6):

You want a double equals:

```
if (length == width)
```

A single equals (`=`) performs assignment, double equals (`==`) performs a comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much... I was literally sitting there looking at the code for 10 minutes trying to figure out where I went wrong. That makes sense considering >= and <= are chosen to represent greater than or equal to or less than or equal to. It works correctly now!

Answer (score 3):

In your if-statement you are **assigning** `width` to `length`, **not comparing**.

It should be: `if (length == width)`

The reason why your if-statement evaluates to `true` is because it checks whether the result of the evaluation (which is the value of `length`) is **different from zero.**

That's because a `bool` is internally represented as an `int`, where `false` is defined as `0` and `true` else.

And since `width` is usually not `0` it would always result in `true`. 
You can test it out by entering `0` for `width`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would recommend is looking into using a debugger to step through each line of your code as it runs one at a time. If you are using VS you have one built right in!

I think if you used a debugger you would have noticed that when the if was running it was doing the assignment rather than the comparison. Just a thought for the future.

I'm sure everyone can say they have caught many silly bugs with a debugger. Good job :)